# C#: How to load a private key into RsaSecurityKey in .net Framework/Standard?

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa, signing

I need to generate an RsaSecurityKey with a private key to sign a JWT.

I have code working in net5.0 but I need that code to work in a .net Standard/Framework library.

Here is the working code:

```
        private static RsaSecurityKey GetRsaKey(byte[] privateKey)
        {
            using RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);

            rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKey), out int _);
            RSAParameters @params = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

            return new RsaSecurityKey(@params);
        }
```

Unfortunately, `rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey` is not available in .net Standard.

I have not been able to find how to replace that piece.

Would anyone know how we are meant to do that with .net Framework?

Thank you.

Comment: You can define  `private key` in `Web.config` and get from it.

Comment: @MukarramJavid that only applies for .net framework asp.net, not for .net core

Comment: A convenient way is to use BouncyCastle and import the PKCS#1 key e.g. with `PemReader`.

Comment: @DanielA.White It works in .NET 5.0 too. Read `Keys` from appSetting.json from `ConfigurationManager` class

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in .net 4.0 and higher. I had the same requirement
the code uses **bouncycastle** and jose.jwt from nuget to generate a jwt.

This is the code fragment I found and tested it works.

[GIT Link](https://gist.github.com/ssippe/8fc11c4d7e766e66f06db0431dba3f0a)

In the  main function

```
claims2 gives you back the json payload you passed

jwt = token
```

you can test it on jwt.io
put the jwt in the section and the bottom paste the public and private .

If it is a valid signature will be valid

claims is the payload.

Hope this helps you